# Can I modify the target of a pointer passed as parameter?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, scope

Can a function change the target of a pointer passed as parameter so that the effect remains outside the function?

```
void load(type *parameter)
{
    delete parameter;
    parameter = new type("second");
}

type *pointer = new type("first");
load(pointer);
```

In this minimal example, will `pointer` point to the second allocate object? If not, how can I get this kind of behavior?

Update: To clarify my intention, here is the code I would use if the parameter would be a normal type instead of a pointer. In this case I would simply use references.

```
void load(type &parameter)
{
    parameter = type("second");
}

type variable("first");
load(&variable);
```

That's easy but I try to do the same thing with pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

`parameter` will get a copy of the value of `pointer` in this case. So it is a new variable. Any change you make to it is only visible with in the function scope. `pointer` stays unmodified.

You have to pass `the pointer` by reference

```
void load(type *& parameter)
                ^
{
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this concept. It works as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Only the `delete parameter;` part doesn't work. I results in access violation. Can I somehow free the memory before assigning the new object?

Comment: Forget what I've said. I just passed the pointer reference through two nested functions and though I could delete in the first and pass to the second. In other words I tried to pass a dead pointer. But if I only delete right before new allocation, everything works fine.

Comment: @danijar Ya just remember to set it to `NULL` after deleting. That way you can do safe delete more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the pointer by reference:

```
void load(type *&parameter);
```

See for example http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `double` pointers.

```
void load(type** parameter)
{
    delete *parameter;
    *parameter = new type("second");
}

type *pointer = new type("first");
load(&pointer);
```

But since you are using cpp you can use `references`